# How to change default timezone for Active Record in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone, rails-activerecord

In my `application.rb` I came across the following comment

```
# Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
# Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
 config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
```

As you see from above, I've made `config.time_zone` to EST time.  However, still when records are created in the DB, it looks like `datetime` is being stored in UTC format.

In the above comment, they say

> ...and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone...

How can I do that, and where?

Also, I'll be deploying this on heroku as well and i'd like the setting to carry over

Comment: In MySQL datetime is a timezone-less type. I.e. it could be in any timezone you want. If you treat it as UTC that's fine. But beware if somebody's looking into your database directly and interpret it differently.

Answer (score 198, accepted):

adding following to `application.rb` works

```
 config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
 config.active_record.default_timezone = :local # Or :utc
```

Comment: It's working for me with this: `config.time_zone = 'London'`
`config.active_record.default_timezone = :local`

Comment: You can see all the Time Zones by running this in `rails c` - `ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.map(&:name)`

Comment: Thanks so much!  I'd been struggling with this as well.  I have an inherited legacy PHP app that interacts with the same mysql database and stores all times as local; updating it to use UTC was not an option.


What I had previously accomplished nothing:

`config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'`
`config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'`


but setting it to the :local symbol did the trick.

Comment: Using `config.active_record.default_timezone = :local` without setting `config.time_zone` worked for me.

Comment: The rails guides say that `config.active_record.default_timezone` should only be set to `:local` or `:utc`. I assume that anything else would have unexpected results.

Comment: @DeanPerry You must make separate answer with your comments!

Comment: You can see all the Time Zones by running this in `rake time:zones:all`

Comment: default_timezone ONLY accept :local or :utc.. anything else will not work..  Yeah it's rather limited in functionality and the name of the var doesn't really portray that well.

Comment: _config.active_record.default_timezone_ is deprecated after Rails 3.2.13, and causes problems when used in combination with delayed_job. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22189490/why-is-the-timezone-off-in-delayed-job/22214040#22214040

Comment: Dean Perry's solution worked for me using rails 3.2.14

Comment: See all available timezones with `rake:time:all`

Comment: Don't forget to restart your server after you add this lines of codes.

Comment: See all available timezones with `rake time:zones` in Rails 5.

Answer (score 247):

I have decided to compile this answer because all others seem to be incomplete.

> **config.active_record.default_timezone** determines whether to use Time.local (if set to :local) or Time.utc (if set to :utc) when pulling dates and times from the database. The default is :utc.
>   http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html

---

If you want to change **Rails** timezone, but continue to have **Active Record** save in the database in **UTC**, use

```
# application.rb
config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
```

---

If you want to change **Rails** timezone **AND** have **Active Record** store times in this timezone, use

```
# application.rb
config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

**Warning**: you really should think twice, even thrice, before saving times in the database in a non-UTC format.

> **Note**
>   Do not forget to restart your Rails server after modifying `application.rb`.

---

Remember that `config.active_record.default_timezone` can take only two values

- **:local** (converts to the timezone defined in `config.time_zone`)
- **:utc** (converts to UTC)

---

Here's how you can find all available timezones

```
rake time:zones:all
```

Comment: This seems like the most complete / accurate answer -- @Omnipresent

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It is more complete.

Comment: @Mihai-AndreiDinculescu Do you think that is better to store the `datetime` values in **UTC** in the database and then just change them in the **frontend** like with [`moment.js`](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) or what do you suggest in order to show this data in the correct time zone for any user?

Comment: @AlexVentura Yes, people smarter than me agreed a long time ago that storing dates in UTC is the best way to go.

Comment: Yeah I got it. But what do you suggest to implement in rails views to show the correct values for any user with different time zone?

Comment: @AlexVentura You can't unless you get them to tell you their machine's timezone. With a little javascript that shouldn't be hard. Assuming this javascript gives you seconds +/- UTC (e.g. 3600 is +1 hour) you can use it in the controller `before` filter like this: `Time.zone = Time.find_zone! params.fetch(:utc_offset)`

Comment: It may be simpler to just use `moment.js` seeing as javascript is necessary.

Comment: What is `Rails timezone` used for?

Answer (score 34):

I came to the same conclusion as Dean Perry after much anguish.  `config.time_zone = 'Adelaide'` and `config.active_record.default_timezone = :local` was the winning combination.  Here's [what I found](https://gist.github.com/3444459) during the process.

Comment: This is the right answer, default_timezone accepts only :local or :utc

Answer (score 24):

In my case (Rails 5), I ended up adding these 2 lines in my `app/config/environments/development.rb`

```
config.time_zone = "Melbourne"
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

That's it! And to make sure that Melbourne was read correctly, I ran the command in my terminal:

`bundle exec rake time:zones:all`

and Melbourne was listing in the timezone I'm in!

Comment: What if I want every user to see date-time values in their own time zone?

Comment: @AlexVentura when you show date-time values to your users, convert it to their time zones. Making the database records persistent is a better practice

Answer (score 12):

If you want to set the timezone to UTC globally, you can do the following in Rails 4:

```
# Inside config/application.rb
config.time_zone = "UTC"
config.active_record.default_timezone = :utc
```

Be sure to restart your application or you won't see the changes.

Answer (score 5):

In Ruby on Rails 6.0.1 go to **config** > **locales** > **application.rb** and add the following:

```
require_relative 'boot'

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module CrudRubyOnRails6
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 6.0

    config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
    config.time_zone = 'Lima'

    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration can go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded after loading
    # the framework and any gems in your application.
  end
end
```

You can see that I am configuring the time zone with 2 lines:

```
config.active_record.default_timezone =: local
config.time_zone = 'Lima'
```

I hope it helps those who are working with Ruby on Rails 6.0.1

Answer (score 4):

I had to add this block to my `environment.rb` file and all was well :)

```
Rails.application.configure do
    config.time_zone = "Pacific Time (US & Canada)"
    config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
end
```

- I added it **before** the line `Rails.application.initialize!`

Answer (score 3):

On rails 4.2.2, go to `application.rb` and use `config.time_zone='city'` (e.g.:'London' or 'Bucharest' or 'Amsterdam' and so on).

It should work just fine. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

for Chinese user, just add two lines below to you `config/application.rb` :

```
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
config.time_zone = 'Beijing'
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want local time to set, add the following text in `application.rb`

```
config.time_zone = 'Chennai'

# WARNING: This changes the way times are stored in the database (not recommended)
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

Then restart your server

Comment: default_timezone accepts one of two options.. :local or :utc..  it doesn't accept a specific time zone, so this will not work..   you need to set default_timezone to :local