# created_at in where statement and timezone

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, date, timezone

I'm trying to retrieve all the entries of the day in my model:

```
where('date(created_at) = date(?)', Date.today)
```

But, because of the timezone (My local time is UTC+2), I don't have the expected result. For example, if an entry has been created one minute after midnight, in the database, it will be stored at 22:01 (so not "Date.today").

Is there a way to do that ?

**EDIT:**

As the admin of the website, I want to display the number of the entries on my local time "today" (It's only for statistics purpose!). So I want to keep timestamps store in utc, but convert them to my local timezone during this request!

Comment: Using a before_filter to set the correct TimeZone?

Comment: Yes : `before_filter do Time.zone = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new('Paris') end`

Comment: Try `TimeZone.new('Paris')` and then `Time.zone.now` to get the changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the correct time zone in several ways. One is described in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6118837/567126

> adding following to application.rb works
>
> config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'

Comment: Isn't it a good thing that activerecord stores timestamps in UTC ?

Comment: Yeah, I think you are right. Timestamps should be stored in a standardized way.

Comment: But on the other hand, it seems that ActiveRecord stores the timestamps in the local timezone per default: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Timestamp.html

Answer (score 0):

```
where('date(created_at) = ?', Time.zone.now.to_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Time in the database should be stored as UTC. This way, when you do a worldwide website, you can serve each user with their own timezone.

It's the UI (views) responsibility to show the time in the user's local timezone.

For your **where** you should use **Time.now.utc** 
This way, you are searching the DB with the common UTC.