# Upgrading from Rails 2.3 to Rails 3 - Timezone issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails 2.3 app that is full of data timestamped with the local timezone (EST) as was the convention with Rails 2.3.  The problem is that now I am upgrading to Rails 3.2 and I want to avoid going and updating all those timestamps to UTC which is the Rails 3.2 convention.  What is the best approach?  I can't seem to figure out a way to tell Rails that the data in the database is in the EST timezone so it can appropriately accomodate timezones calculations.  Surely others have run into this?  Thanks!

Comment: does this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118779/how-to-change-default-timezone-for-activerecord-in-rails3 perhaps you can tell us what have you tried and where are you stucked?

Answer (score 0):

Got it working!  This was the configuration that needed to be added:

**application.rb:**

```
config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

Now it assumes the data in the database is in the **local** timezone specified as **'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'**.