# How do I format datetime in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, view

In my Rails view, I have the below code that displays a datetime.

```
<%= link_to timeslot.opening, [@place, timeslot] %>
```

The result of this line is below:

```
2013-02-02 01:00:00 UTC
```

How do I change this so it displays as:

```
2/2/13: X:00 PST
```

Comment: Try - timeslot.opening.strftime(%d/%m/%y: %H:%M:%S %Z)

Comment: You could use the [**stamp** gem](https://github.com/jeremyw/stamp) or [**strftime**](http://strfti.me/).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use ruby's `strftime()` on dates/datetimes:

```
<%= link_to timeslot.opening.strftime("%Y %m %d"), [@place, timeslot] %>
```

Have a look at [the documentation](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime) to find out how the formatting works.

Comment: Thanks!  This and the documentation is super helpful. I haven't been able to find how to convert a time between timezones.  In my example, the time is currently in UTC but would like it to show PST.  Do you know how I could enable this?

Comment: Welcome :) Refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118779/how-to-change-default-timezone-for-activerecord-in-rails3

Answer (score 9):

You should use a helper for this.

If you want to convert from UTC to PST you can use the `in_time_zone` method

```
def convert_time(datetime)
  time = Time.parse(datetime).in_time_zone("Pacific Time (US & Canada)")
  time.strftime("%-d/%-m/%y: %H:%M %Z")
end

<%= link_to convert_time(timeslot.opening), [@place, timeslot] %>
```

Answer (score 4):

For the format you have requested:

```
<%= link_to timeslot.opening.strftime(%d/%m/%y: %H:%M:%S %Z), [@place, timeslot] %>
```

More options available here:

http://rorguide.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/date-time-formats-in-ruby-on-rails.html

Answer (score 0):

to get the precise date formatting that you are looking for in your example use the following strftime format string `"%-d/%-m/%y: %k:00 PST"`

However, that may not be exactly what you want.Please clarify in your question (a) what you want to do with the time field (e.g. are you always wanting to display a time on the hour? X:00) and (b) are you always wanting to report PST times or do you want to print the actual timezone, or do you want to convert to PST??