# Rails column type for moment.js formatted date and time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, model, momentjs

I am building a rails app, where the user picks up a date from a date picker and a time from the time picker. Both the date and time have been formatted using moment js to show the date and time in the following way:

```
moment().format('LL'); //January 23,2017
moment().format('LTS'); //1:17:54 PM
```

I read this answer with guidelines about selection of a proper column type.
[Is there documentation for the Rails column types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889048/is-there-documentation-for-the-rails-column-types)

Ideally, I should be using :date, :time or :timestamp for this. But since the dates are formatted, should I be using :string instead?

Which would be the correct and appropriate column type to use in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store a time reference in your database you should use one of the types the database offers you. I'll explain this using MySQL (which is the one I have used the most) but the explanation should be similar in other database servers.

- If you use a `timestamp` column you will be using just 4 bytes of storage, which is always a good new since it makes smaller indexes, uses less memory in temporal tables during the internal database operations and so on. However, `timestamp` has a smaller range than `datetime` so you will only be able to store values from year 1970 up to year 2038 more or less
- If you use `datetime` you will be able to store a wider range (from year 1001 to year 9999) with the same precision (second). The bad consequence is that a higher range needs more memory, making it a bit slower.

There are some other differences between these two column types that don't fit in this answer, but you should keep an eye on before deciding.

- If you use `varchar`, which is the default column type for text attributes in Ruby on Rails, you will be forced to convert from text to datetime and vice-versa every time you need to use that field. In addition, ordering or filtering on that column will be very inefficient because the database will need to convert all strings into dates before filtering or sorting, making it impossible to use indexes on that column.
- If you need sub-second precision, you can use `bigint` to meet your requirements, as MySQL does not provide a date specific type for this purpose

In general, I recommend using `timestamp` if your application requirements fit the `timestamp` limitation. Otherwise, use `datetime`, but I strongly discourage you to use `varchar` for this purpose.

**EDIT: Formatting**

The way you store dates in database is completely different from the way you display it to the user. You can create a `DateTime` object using `DateTime.new(year, month, day, hour, minute, second)` and assign that object to your model. By the time you save it into database, ActiveRecord will be in charge of converting the DateTime object into the appropiate database format.

In order to display a value that is already stored in database in a specific format (in a view, API response, etc.) you can hava a look at other posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15625947/how-do-i-format-datetime-in-rails).

Comment: Thanks!              Will I need to convert the date in any specific format to store it on :timestamp or :datetime? Because I will receive the date as Month DD, YYYY and time as hours:min:sec am/pm from the user

Answer (score 1):

You can have a timestamp column in your database, and then parse the request to a ruby datetime object like this:

```
d = Time.parse(params[:date])
t = Time.new(params[:time])
dt = DateTime.new(d.year, d.month, d.day, t.hour, t.min, t.sec, t.zone)
#now simply use dt to your datetime column
```

On Postgres you can save a ruby DateTime object straight into a postgres **timestamp field**, e.g

```
  User.first.update_attribute('updated_at', dt )
```

Another option is to concatenate your date and time strings into one and then u can do a one-liner:

```
  User.last.update_attribute('created_at', Time.parse('January 23,2017 1:17:54 PM'))
```

I'm pretty sure this will work on MySQL datetime or timestamp as well.

Credit to david grayson [Ruby: combine Date and Time objects into a DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12181444/ruby-combine-date-and-time-objects-into-a-datetime)

Comment: So I can have a date formatted in any way stored under the :date column type? Isn't there a particular format the date should be in?

Comment: not under date since you want the date AND the time. use either timestamp or datetime for the column

Comment: will any other formatting be needed? Like removing the comma and all?

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I get it now