# Cannot set Heroku timezone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, timezone

I need to have my app display times in a local timezone.
Locally I'm using Time.zone = "Athens" in application.rb and it works fine.

For Heroku I used "heroku config:add TZ=Europe/Athens". This works fine for every operation I do from the command line, but it doesn't apply to my app.

For example

**heroku run date**: 
    Running `date` attached to terminal... up, run.4786
    Tue Apr 23 15:13:51 EEST 2013

**heroku run console**:

**Order.last.created_at**
    => Tue, 23 Apr 2013 13:15:53 EEST +03:00

**Time.zone**
=> (GMT+02:00) Athens

But I put this in my rails view: 
     <%= Time.zone %>
And I get this:
    (GMT+00:00) UTC
And my times appear in UTC time in the actual app.

So, how do I set the timezone to apply to the actual rails application on heroku (and not just the console).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to set the time zone in your application.rb as follows:

```
config.time_zone = 'Athens'
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

config.active_record.default_timezone determines whether to use Time.local (if set to :local) or Time.utc (if set to :utc) when pulling dates and times from the database. The default is :utc for Rails, although Active Record defaults to :local when used outside of Rails.

from: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-active-record

Comment: **config.time_zone = 'Athens'** was what I needed. I was using **Time.zone = 'Athens'**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the time zone in `application.rb` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6118837/2942)?

```
 config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
 config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
```

Answer (score 0):

For setting up the timezone in heroku you can set it from terminal

```
$ heroku config:add TZ="Asia/Jerusalem"
```

Source 
https://coderwall.com/p/j9_e8a/set-timezone-for-your-heroku-app