# DateTime is not being saved when TImeZone is set in application.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I ran across an issue today, that leaves me a bit confused.
Whenever I try to save a DateTime to the Database, it seems to work - but as soon as I try to retrive it again, I'm getting back **nil**.
This does not only happen on Records I'm saving, but also on the **created_at** and the **updated_at** field. 
I was able to trace it down, by removing

```
    config.time_zone = "Bern"
    config.active_record.default_timezone = "Bern"
```

From my application.rb - and it seems to work flawlessly again.

Is there any way that I can work around this, and actually save the records in my (Bern) timezone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that "Bern" isn't a valid time zone identifier for Rails, and that that's causing the problem.

According to [comments on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118779/how-to-change-default-timezone-for-activerecord-in-rails3), you can use the following command to see the valid time zone IDs:

```
rails c - ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.map(&:name)
```

However, I'd strongly recommend against storing timestamps in your local time zone anyway - store them in UTC, and then convert to the local time zone of the user where appropriate. Aside from anything else, this avoids issues around daylight saving transitions.

Comment: According to that List, "Bern" is a valid TimeZone - I suspected it to be "Europe/Bern" too. Thank you for elaborating on this tough, and yes, it makes perfect sense to not store them with the local time.

Comment: @mlang: Hmm. Europe/Bern isn't a validate TZDB ID, if that's relevant. Looking at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html there's a mapping from "Bern" to "Europe/Berlin". I confess I'm not a Rails person or even a Ruby person, so it's not entirely clear to me which bit does what...

Comment: Hm.. I see, I might need to simply use "Europe/Berlin". But I'm going the way to store it in UTC, which makes it a bit easier to maintain too. I dont know what I was thinking to store Data in local time.

Comment: @mlang: Okay, cool - if it removes the need to get the time zone right at all, that's definitely even better :) (I'd expected that you might need it in the other direction for display, for example.) Good luck!