# Rails: undefined method `Europe/Rome' for Time:Class

Tags: ruby, time, ruby-on-rails-4, timezone

I have this error when I create a shift...

```
ActiveRecord::MultiparameterAssignmentErrors (2 error(s) on assignment of multiparameter attributes [error on assignment [8, 0, 1970, 1, 1] to inizio (undefined method `Europe/Rome' for Time:Class),error on assignment [16, 0, 1970, 1, 1] to fine (undefined method `Europe/Rome' for Time:Class)]):
  app/controllers/shifts_controller.rb:43:in `create'
```

In the application.rb i have

```
config.time_zone = 'Europe/Rome'
config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Europe/Rome'
```

the Model is

```
class Shift < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_initialize do
    self.stato ||= true
    self.inizio ||= Time.zone.now
    self.fine ||= Time.zone.now
  end

end
```

The Controller is : 
http://nopaste.info/3268dc795c.html

Migrate is : 
http://nopaste.info/eb674af117.html

Comment: Either duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118779/how-to-change-default-timezone-for-activerecord-in-rails3 or try "Rome" instead of "Europe/Rome".

Comment: Do you have your application uploaded on Github or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `active_record.default_timezone` accepts only `:local` or `:utc`, so you must change settings in this way:

```
config.time_zone = 'Rome'
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

Dopodiché ti suggerisco di scrivere sempre in inglese mentre programmi per avere coerenza all'interno del codice.
*And by the way, I suggest you to always type in English when coding to improve consistency*

View this [GIST](https://gist.github.com/jbarona/3444459) that show some details on why to use `:local`.
Watch also the second answer on this post, which is the correct one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12127232/312907

And be careful, it's `'Rome'`, not `'Europe/Rome'`

Answer (score 0):

For Europe/Rome rails has actually mapped it to just 'Rome' so you should be able to do this:

```
config.time_zone = 'Rome'
config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Rome'
```

You can find all the timezone mappings in the documentation for [ActiveSupport::TimeZone](http://www.omniref.com/ruby/gems/activesupport/4.0.2/classes/ActiveSupport%3a%3aTimeZone#%3a%3aMAPPING)

Comment: I'd just add 'Europe/Rome' or equivalents for other capitals is just an identifier string for timezone information (`tzinfo` of `TZInfo::TimeZoneProxy` class).