# Why is the timezone off in delayed_job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone, delayed-job, timezone-offset

In my Rails app, when I create a background job using the [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) gem, I get all times offset by 6 hours.

My understanding is that [delayed_job uses your timezone](http://www.gregbenedict.com/2009/08/19/is-delayed-job-run_at-datetime-giving-you-fits/), but it's like it's using the wrong one.  Instead of being -6 hours from UTC ([CST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Time_Zone) is my time zone), it's -12 hours!

Here's a bit of view code to illustrate. Note:

- *Time.now* gives **2014-03-04 23:26:55 -0600**
- *Time.now.utc* gives **2014-03-05 05:26:55 UTC**
- but delayed_job's idea of just a few seconds ago is **2014-03-04 17:26:53 -0600**

My View:

```
#delayed_jobs/index.html.erb

<h1>All Background Jobs</h1>
<p>The time now is: <%= Time.now %> </p>
<p>The time UTC is: <%= Time.now.utc %> </p>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Queue</th>
    <th>Created At</th>
    <th>Run At</th>
  </tr>

<% @delayed_jobs.each do |dj| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= dj.id %></td>
    <td><%= dj.queue %></td>
    <td><%= dj.created_at %></td>
    <td><%= dj.run_at %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

Output:
[image: output of index view]

I can create jobs any of these three ways, and will get the same *created_at* time:

```
MyClass.delay.foo
MyClass.delay(run_at: 0.minutes.from_now).foo
MyClass.delay(run_at: 0.minutes.from_now.getutc).foo
```

My configuration has:

```
#config/application.rb

config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'
config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'
```

Comment: In your config/application.rb did you happen to set:     config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'? If, so try setting it to UTC or just commenting it out.

Comment: Odd. Setting only config.active_record.default_timezone makes delayed_job correct, but doesn't work for any other active record object.

Comment: Thanks! This led me down the path to a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was in my config/application.rb as @rainkinz suggested, specifically the 2nd line:

```
config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'
config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'
```

Apparently the [default_timezone setting is deprecated after Rails 3.2.13](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/default_timezone/class), which I just upgraded from a few days ago.

When I changed it to only have the local time zone set:

```
config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'
#config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'
```

This fixed the problem. All active record objects still seem to have the correct time when saved, as do delayed_jobs.