# Why is delayed_job recording an incorrect time stamp in the delayed_jobs table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I feel I'm having a similar issue to this post [Why is the timezone off in delayed_job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22189490/why-is-the-timezone-off-in-delayed-job)

I've setup my time_zone in `config/application.rb` as follows:

```
module Bane
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.time_zone 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
  end
end
```

When looking at my delayed_jobs.log I record the time stamp shows correctly.  However, when I look at my `delayed_jobs` table it shows `2015-11-19 14:25:11.637` which isn't what I had expected (`2015-11-19 09:25:11.xxx`).

Comment: What does the `Time.zone` returns, if you run it in the rails console?

Comment: `Rails.application.config.time_zone
 => "Eastern Time (US & Canada)" `

Comment: Strange, it should work then (based on this: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job_active_record/blob/master/lib/delayed/backend/active_record.rb#L110)

Comment: Maybe you just changed the config, and haven't restarted the `background_job` process yet?

Comment: iirc Rails converts the time to the zone when it pulls it from the database.  It doesn't change the timezone for the database.

Comment: @YuryLebedev well the time_zone has been set prior to installing the delayed_job gem.  I am using SQL Server with TinyTDS so I wonder if something is getting lost along the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you set the `config.time_zone` setting Rails still stores the dates using UTC, but converts them to the desired time zone once the record is loaded.

There is an another setting — `config.active_record.default_timezone`, which affects the way dates are stored in the db, but as far as I know it can only be set to either `:local`, either (the default) `:utc`. But if you can set your server time zone to `EST` then, I believe, it should work.

EDIT: It seems that you can actually set any timezone for the `default_timezone` also. For example: `config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'`.