# How to change ActiveRecord timezone?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, timezone

I need to turn off the time conversions between Rails application and Mysql.

This comment at [ActiveRecord source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/55cedf288e958cb79cd4a94b08bf7da5e1c3d3f8/activerecord/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb#L12) say that:

```
  # Timestamps are in UTC by default but you can use the local timezone by setting:
  #
  #   config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

But, my server uses the `UTC` timezone and it'll no make difference if use `:local` or `:utc`  option. The needed timezone is `'Brasilia'`.

The Rails console on production server show the conversions:

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails c 
Loading production environment (Rails 4.1.4)
2.0.0 :001 > Time.current
 => Wed, 13 Aug 2014 17:34:15 BRT -03:00 
2.0.0 :002 > Schedule.where(startDateTimeSchedule: Time.current)
  Schedule Load (1.0ms)  SELECT `Schedule`.* FROM `Schedule`  WHERE `Schedule`.`startDateTimeSchedule` = '2014-08-13 20:34:25'
```

P.S.: The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6118837/740394) of the highly voted question about this subject is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a new default timezone in your config/application.rb

```
config.time_zone = 'Brasilia'
```

If you have users of whom you know the timezone, you can also convert them correctly by adding this code to your ApplicationController

```
around_filter :user_time_zone, :if => :current_user

def user_time_zone(&block)
  Time.use_zone(current_user.timezone, &block)
end
```