# ActiveRecord with timezone not working as expected

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a model called Order which has a DATETIME (Mysql) column called expiration

I do the following:

```
order = Order.last

wanted_time = Time.use_zone('Pacific Time (US & Canada)') { Time.now.end_of_day.to_datetime }
```

And wanted_time gives me: `Thu, 20 Nov 2014 23:59:59 -0800`

However, when I do:

```
order.expiration = wanted_time
```

When I try to fetch order.expiration, I get:

```
Fri, 21 Nov 2014 07:59:59 UTC +00:00
```

Why is that? If I specifically have defined the zone I wanted to store it with?

Comment: did you update order after assigning `wanted_time` value to `order.expiration`. If Yes, can you please add that code also

Answer (score 0):

See this:  [How to change default timezone for Active Record in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118779/how-to-change-default-timezone-for-activerecord-in-rails-3)

Change application.rb to have the following lines... I'm guessing theres a difference between rails and db.

config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'

Comment: Sorry, but that does not answer my question.

Comment: what is your AR timezone set to?