# set created_at with local time zone in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Set the created_at to local time zone. I deployed my app in heroku. But while creating creating record created_at is taking heroku time but not local time.
For example: in heroku time is: 26-06-2015
but in my local machine time is: 25-06-2015

I want to store my local machine time not heroku time.
I tried to put the below code in application.rb

```
  config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
  config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

But not working. Can anyone help me out of this

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively try this

```
config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118779/how-to-change-default-timezone-for-activerecord-in-rails-3) the reference

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

To set time zone on the Heroku server, you will need this:

```
$ heroku config:add TZ="America/New_York"
```

Credit goes [here](http://blog.pardner.com/2012/08/setting-the-default-time-zone-for-a-heroku-app/).

Comment: I want to store local time zone instead of heroku time zone

Comment: Yes but I guess I don't understand the distinction.  If you tell Heroku to use your local time, wouldn't that accomplish your objective?

Comment: If i want to store to amazon ?

Comment: So your app is running on `Heroku`, not your local machine, correct?  If you interact with another service from your app, it is happening on the Heroku server.  You are just controlling Heroku from your local machine (unless you have multiple prod apps, some on Heroku and some on your server...).

Comment: Actually my app is on AWS. Ex: AWS time is 26-06-2015 and my local machine time is 25-06-2015. My requirement is to take the 25-06-2015 but it is taking 26-06-2015.

Comment: So what does Heroku have to do with it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81573/discussion-between-steve-klein-and-sunny).