# Passing date from angular to rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, datetime, timezone, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have a problem with passing date from Angular to Rails. In my project i use datetimepicker directive (https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker) which is using moment js. So when i pick the date it looks like "Wed Aug 05 2015 **11:55:00** GMT+0300 (EEST)". Then this date is passing to rails api and rails converts it in "2015-08-05T**08:55:00**.000Z". So i simply need that the time received by rails was **11:55:00** not **08:55:00**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do need to realize that **Wed Aug 05 2015 11:55:00 GMT+0300** is equal to **2015-08-05T08:55:00.000Z** and that the later date is a translation to UTC of the first one.

To change the timezone in which  Active Record saves in the database, you can use

```
# application.rb
config config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

**Warning**! You really should think twice, even thrice, before saving times in the database in a non-UTC format.

Here's how you can find all available timezones

```
rake:time:all
```

More information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32229086/4304188

Comment: yes, i already did that but i can't figure why i set config.time_zone to anything and it doesn't make any changes? i set config.time_zone to 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)', 'London', 'Kyiv', 'Moskow' etc. but it is still **2015-08-05T08:55:00.000Z**. What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Even if you set `config config.time_zone`, Active Record still uses UTC by default. `config config.time_zone` affects Rails, not Active Record and not the database.

Comment: Have you restarted your server?

Comment: Yes, i have restarted my server with every changes. Sorry but actually i don't understand what i shall to do to write the picked date to the database correctly.

Comment: The two lines found in my answer should achieve that.

Comment: Ok, thnx a lot:) I just confused with all that date formats you know:) i will store dates in database in utc as it is