# Set activerecord default timezone to a specific timezone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I'm using a Rails application to access a database from a legacy application. This application stores all datetime fields using Europe/Madrid timezone.

I tried to set this in my application.rb:

```
config.time_zone = 'Madrid'
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

Unfortunately it didn't worked as I expected. It looks like Rails is using the timezone of my system ( America/Sao_Paulo ). So a date that is stored as:

```
2015-09-09 18:38:01
```

Will be shown with a difference of 5 hours in Rails:

```
2015-09-09 23:38:01
```

Which is the difference between São Paulo and Madrid. It should show 18:38:01 in Rails too since my app's default timezone is Madrid.

Is there a way to force the ActiveRecord timezone without changing my OS timezone?

--- Edit ---

Here is the output that I get:

```
2.1.3 :004 > Time.zone.name
 => "Madrid"
2.1.3 :005 > LogSent.last.sent_date
  LogSent Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `log_sent`.* FROM `log_sent`  ORDER BY `log_sent`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
 => Wed, 09 Sep 2015 23:38:01 CEST +02:00
```

I'm expecting "Wed, 09 Sep 2015 **18**:38:01 CEST +02:00" which is the value stored in database, in Madrid timezone.

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118779/how-to-change-default-timezone-for-active-record-in-rails

Comment: @NickM I already have that but it's not working. Check this http://pastebin.com/BQnE1G55. It should return "Wed, 09 Sep 2015 18:38:01 CEST +02:00" ( the value stored in database, in Madrid timezone ) instead of "Wed, 09 Sep 2015 23:38:01 CEST +02:00"

Answer (score 1):

I know this was 3 years ago, but maybe somebody else will have the same question like I did.

When you put `config.active_record.default_timezone = :local` in your configuration, AR assumes that DB has local timezone, local here meaning the one on your computer. It's pretty hard to change that behaviour, you'd have to monkey-patch both ActiveRecord and ActiveModel.

Trick, however, is to convince Ruby (not Rails) that Madrid is your local time. You can do that by setting `TZ` environment variable to `Madrid`.

You can put in your `config/initializers/timezone.rb` the following

```
ENV["TZ"] = "Madrid"
```

Or just set the env variable before running the server as normal,
and don't forget about `config.active_record.default_timezone = :local`.

This way all values read and written to DB will be in Madrid timezone

Comment: This is the correct answer when you have `datetime` fields in MySQL using a particular time zone, running in a server that is set in UTC, and you can't do anything to fix it without a major refactor in a legacy app.

Answer (score 0):

How do you save `sent_date` attribute?

Remember that if you use `DateTime.now`, it will retrieve the current DateTime of your system (Sao Paulo time). Instead, you should use `Time.zone.now`, which will retrieve the current DateTime configured in `application.rb`

Comment: It's saved by a legacy PHP application. It's not saved by Rails. Unfortunately changing the PHP application is not possible, but at least I know that the date is always in Madrid timezone.