# beginning_of_day doesn't calculate time correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I got two models `Shift` and `ShiftDetail`. I have a Shift model methods that adds `ShiftDetails` automatically:

```
def add_shift_details
    (0..6).each do |i|
        shift_detail = ShiftDetail.new
        t1 = Time.now

        shift_detail.weekday = i
        shift_detail.start_time = t1.beginning_of_day
        shift_detail.end_time = t1.end_of_day
        self.shift_details << shift_detail
    end
end
```

But when i save the instance the database is populated with

```
["start_time", "2016-03-02 23:00:00.000000"]
["end_time", "2016-03-03 22:59:59.999999"]
```

I am using Rails 4.2.5.1 and ruby 2.3.0p0

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

When I test it in 'rails c', it works as expected:

```
2.3.0 :001 > Time.now.beginning_of_day
=> 2016-03-03 00:00:00 +0100 
2.3.0 :002 > Time.now.end_of_day
=> 2016-03-03 23:59:59 +0100
```

Comment: Is the time on your machine set correctly?

Comment: It is. Im on a mac an the system time is correct.

Comment: Check your time zone in `application.rb` file

Comment: My time zone setting is config.time_zone = 'Berlin'. This is correct. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database stores `DateTime` in the UTC timezone while Rails works with the Berlin timezone. Berlin's midnight (GMT+1) is not equal with UTC's (GMT) midnight :)

You have two options:

1. Have your algorithm work with an UTC timezone
   You can use `Time.now.utc` or `DateTime.now.new_offset(0)`
2. Have your database store dates in your specific timezone (Berlin's in this case). I highly advise not to do this.

Check out this post for more information:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32229086/4304188