# How do I save a datetime with a different timezone than what is set in config.time_zone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In `application.rb` I have `config.timezone = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)` but I'm adding a feature that needs to save objects with different timezones. Is there a way to override the default timezone? Everytime I try to save in a different timezone it defaults to Pacific.

Comment: I'm assuming you've parsed the Time from a time string containing zone information, like so:

    `Time.strptime("2016-05-25 01:33 +05:30", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %Z")`

Is your problem that ActiveRecord does not save this time object in the zone represented by %Z?

Comment: I'm using a jquery datetimepicker that inputs that formats it as `2016-05-25 12:00am` and ActiveRecord will save it as `Sat, 25 May 2016 00:00:00 PDT -07:00`. If I try to update that datetime attribute `Object.update_attribute(:time_field, Time.in_time_zone('Hawaii')` it will still save it in pacific time

Comment: This probably happens because the ActiveRecord timezone is still set to 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'. Refer to this answer for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118779/how-to-change-default-timezone-for-active-record-in-rails

Comment: yes but is there a way to keep that default Pacific Time but also save things in a different TimeZone?

Comment: I don't see any built-in provisions for that - the recommended approach is to let the database store all time information in the same time_zone and let the application perform the time_zone conversions. I guess your approach of saving the time_zone in a separate field is the way to go if you really need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Does it default to pacific or does it calculate the time in pacific ?

Usually setting the time to a different time zone would just translate the time to what it would be in the default one. You would have to save a second variable with the time zone if you wanted to get it back to what it was and then calculate what the time would be in that time zone.

Comment: It defaults to pacific and I do currently have a timezone field to convert it over and method that uses it but it would be better if I could just save it based on the string input with a timezone

Answer (score 0):

If you need different time zones, you can change it with a around_filter in your controller.

Read more about it [here](http://ilikestuffblog.com/2011/02/03/how-to-set-a-time-zone-for-each-request-in-rails/)

Comment: Pavan's answer is nearly exactly how I do it.