# Rails: How to store date in "Chennai" Timezone in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4, timezone

In the rails application by default created_at and updated_at filed are stored in UTC format. i want to store created_at and updated_at field in my local timezone i.e in "Chennai" Timezone.

I wrote below to lines in my application.rb file but still my created_at and updated_at fields dates are saved in UTC timezone and not in my local timezone.

```
 config.time_zone = 'Chennai'
 config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

Please let me know what wrong i am doing here??

Thanks,

Sanjay Salunkhe

Answer (score 2):

To make this happen you need to just add this to your `application.rb`

```
config.time_zone = 'Chennai' 
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

[How to change default timezone for Active Record in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118779/how-to-change-default-timezone-for-active-record-in-rails/)

Also one optional but very important thing that you should also do is to set the default time of the server or servers( where your rails application is hosted ) to the timezone you are giving in `application.rb` ( in your case which is `'Chennai'`). [For example this is how you can set timezone of an `Ubuntu` server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/323131/setting-timezone-from-terminal/323163).
Its is very important that your server timezone and the default timezone in `application.rb` are same to avoid unnecessary  timezone related issues.