# tests failing after change default timezone for activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, timezone

I have the following method:

```
def track(user)
  user.last_login_from_ip_address = request.env['REMOTE_ADDR']
  user.last_login_at = Time.zone.now
  user
end
```

and in my controller, I do this

`track(user).save!`

I also have the following test to make sure that the user is being tracked correctly:

```
  before do
    @user = create(:user, password: 'P@ssw0rd1', email: 'right@email.com', activation_state: 'active')
    @user.activate!
  end
  it 'should change the last login time' do
    post :authenticate, params
    expect(@user.reload.last_login_at).not_to be_nil
  end
```

until now, it was passing perfectly.
Now, I had to change the timezone in `application.rb` as follows:

`config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Europe/Berlin'`

after I added this line, this test is now failing. there is no `last_login_at` anymore set.
I found this behaviour very weird, and I have no idea what could be causing it

Comment: Like questioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118779/how-to-change-default-timezone-for-active-record-in-rails) you should also set `config.time_zone`.

Comment: Actually, I did that as well

Comment: Where do you actually call `track(user)`?