# Change default timezone in papertrail

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been working with papertrail gem in rails.
It creates the created_at column in versions table which stores the default date time zone as UTC 00:00, I want to change the default timezone for this application to some other time zone.
How to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change default timezone for Active Record in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118779/how-to-change-default-timezone-for-active-record-in-rails)

Comment: No, I have tried doing this that doesn't change the timezone for the paper trail gem

Comment: I had it set to US even though I have nothing in common with it. (Did they set US timezone for me just because they themselves come from US?) Why don't they just use user's OS timezone? That's ridiculous.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue.

In the top menu bar (Dashboard, Events, Alert, Settings, Support), go to setting, profile and change your timezone

Hope this helps.

Daniel