# Rails Time Zone on save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I have a problem with my `time_zone` in Rails APP.

I have it configured to London in my `application.rb`:

```
config.time_zone = 'London'
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

Then, in my controller I have something like this:

```
Element.create(start_hour: Time.strptime('16/04/2018 12:00', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'))
```

What can I do to save this date and when I print the time in the view it returns me the London time?

For example, in the previous example, now in my view: `element.start_hour.strftime('%H:%M')` prints `13:00` but I want that it prints `12:00`

Comment: Have you set ActiveRecord's time zone as well? This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118779/how-to-change-default-timezone-for-active-record-in-rails

Comment: @Gerry, Yes, I have `config.active_record.default_timezone = :local` in my `application.rb` too.

Comment: Have you restart your rails application after changing the application.rb?

Comment: @Salil, No because I haven't changed the `application.rb`

Comment: What is the o/p of `Time.strptime('16/04/2018 12:00', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')` & `Time.strptime('16/04/2018 12:00', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M').zone`

Comment: Also, `config.time_zone` does not change the `:local` timezone. That will be based on system time. Be sure ``date`` returns London time. [update: date the unix command, not ruby]

Comment: @Salil, `'2018-04-16 12:00:00 +0200'` & `'CEST'`

Comment: @JacobVanus, my date unix command (I'm in local) returns spanish date but in production returns UTC+0 and the result in views is the same.

Comment: Now it works! I added `zone` method to `Time` before save the field. `Element.create(start_hour: Time.zone.strptime('16/04/2018 12:00', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'))` then the time to save is transformed to `11:00` before save.

Comment: I'd recommend following Thoughtbot's recommendations for more control over how time zones get saved and display. If you keep the default at UTC, you can do more with controllers/views to reliably ensure you're getting the right output. https://robots.thoughtbot.com/its-about-time-zones