# Rails set config.active_record.default_timezone to value other than :utc or :local

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I have my app time zone set to Pacific.

```
# application.rb: 
config.time_zone = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'
```

My production server time is set to Pacific.  But ActiveRecord sets the per-session postgres time zone to 'UTC':

```
[1] pry(main)> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("show timezone").getvalue(0,0)
  (0.2ms)  show timezone
=> "UTC"
```

The [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html) say my only two options for `config.active_record.default_timezone` are `:utc` and `:local`

Using `:local` is fine for production, but my development server is in a different time zone.

I know it's often recommended to leave all time zone settings to the default UTC, but my app uses postgres's time and date functions extensively for ETL jobs, complex data analysis queries, etc.  I would rather have postgres be my "single source of truth" than rails/ruby, so I'm not interested in answers that tell me to do everything in UTC

Edit: I've confirmed that `config.time_zone` is properly set:

```
[6] pry(main)> Rails.application.config.time_zone
=> "Pacific Time (US & Canada)"
```

and `config.active_record.default_timezone` is set to `:local`

```
[9] pry(main)> Rails.application.config.active_record.default_timezone
=> :local
```

in the same pry session:

```
[10] pry(main)> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("show timezone").getvalue(0,0)
   (0.2ms)  show timezone
=> "Asia/Bangkok"
```

Comment: It sounds at first blush that it is local to the system, but it looks [from reading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32229086/525478), that it may be local to the app. Have you verified that config.timezone to the correct zone, and default_timezone to :local doesn't actually work, independent of the system time zone? I suspect it will. We do this a lot, but the system time is usually set to the preferred timezone, too.

Comment: @BradWerth I added an edit to show that both config vars are set. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the PostgreSQLAdapter [source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-2-0/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb#L710) on github, I saw that a variables hash is checked for the presence of a "timezone" key.

```
      variables = @config.fetch(:variables, {}).stringify_keys

      # If using Active Record's time zone support configure the connection to return
      # TIMESTAMP WITH ZONE types in UTC.
      unless variables["timezone"]
        if ActiveRecord::Base.default_timezone == :utc
          variables["timezone"] = "UTC"
        elsif @local_tz
          variables["timezone"] = @local_tz
        end
      end
```

The [PostgreSQLAdapter docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/PostgreSQLAdapter.html) show that `:variables` is an option in `config/database.yml`, so I just added `variables: {timezone: 'US/Pacific'}` to database.yml.

```
# database.yml
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  variables: {timezone: 'US/Pacific'}
```

Kind of weird that you have to set it here instead of in `config/`, but it works.