# how to convert datetime string to utc in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have date format **Sat, 01 Jan 2000 16:20:00 UTC +00:00**
and i have just take the date time value the given form as "2000-01-01 16:20:00" and from this i have just taken the time  16:20:00 with
`strftime('%H:%M:%S')` now i need to convert this to UTC
Here is the rake file m trying to update, the main problem is the time conversion on by staging environment.

```
bookings = Booking.where(booking_status: 'booked')
                  .where('booking_date = ?', Date.current)
if bookings.present?
  bookings.each do |booking|
    date = booking&.booking_time&.strftime('%H:%M:%S')&.to_time&.utc

    booking.update(booking_status: 'no_show') if date < Time.current
  end
end
```

Comment: Does `DateTime.parse(...)` handle it properly?

Comment: Does sometimes  the `booking_time` of  `booked books` is nil?  How many booking records do you have? Do you set an index on `booking_status` and  `booking_date`? Do not update the records in the loop, use `update_all` will run fasrer.

Comment: Some explanation would help. It seems as if you have a `booking_date` which contains just the date and a `booking_time` which contains just the time, but somehow also has an unused date part of 2000-01-01. And now you want to create a Ruby `Time` object with the date-part from `booking_date` and the time-part from `booking_time` – is that correct? It would help to see the `bookings` database schema and some example entries. BTW: why did you split date and time in the first place? It seems to cause a bit of trouble.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question... Surely if anything, you want to convert the time to UTC **BEFORE (!!)** removing any timezone information via `strftime('%H:%M:%S')`? And wouldn't it have made more sense to give us an example that's not already UTC to begin with? This seems like a pretty pointless question you're asking, where you want to convert a time that's already UTC, into UTC.

Comment: And as mentioned above, this is a bad database design to have `booking_date` and `booking_time` as separate columns. If you want to extract the date information, then this is already available as part of the `booking_time`.

Comment: When posting a question on SO it's (obviously) advisable to hang around awhile to see if readers have any questions about your statement of the problem. We see that you didn't and they did. It's now been 7+ hours since posting and you still haven't returned. Not good.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. @tadman i tried DateTime.parse(..) but it didn't work

Comment: @Stefan i have a list of available booking time so i have a separate column from the booking date and booking time. The available time is same for all the following dates.

Comment: Please @San edit your question and add the error or misbehavior you ran into, also clarify that your issue is not that the rake task is slow

Comment: edited my answer so you can parse to UTC @San

Answer (score 2):

First I am agreed with the comments above seems like you don't really need that extra column, instead of that you could define a function within your model that returns the value when needed:

```rb
def book_status
   date = booking_time&.strftime('%H:%M:%S')&.to_time&.utc
   date < Time.current ? 'no_show' : 'booked'
end
```

Then to any instance of your book model, you can access his status like this: `my_book.book_status`.

But if you really need/want that extra column there is a way to speed up the process, the problem you have in your code is that you perform **n** SQL queries to update each item plus if you use the **update** function you are also triggering all the ActiveRecord callbacks for each instance of book, a possible workaround is to use the [update_all](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all), but take into account that if you need callbacks then you need to keep it the way you have it, in any case, this is how to do it with **update_all** (should speed up the process):

```rb
books_ids = Booking.where(booking_status: 'booked').
                  where('booking_date = ?', Date.current).
                  select { |book_i| book_i.booking_time&.strftime('%H:%M:%S')&.to_time&.utc < Time.current }.map(&:id)

Book.where(id: books_ids).update_all(booking_status: 'no_show')
```

The above code will generate 2 queries instead of **n** one to get the books_ids that you want to update and the second one to really update those books (without trigger callbacks), in any case, I recommend the first approach instead of this.

A third option is to do it as needed like below:

```rb
def book_status
   date = booking_time&.strftime('%H:%M:%S')&.to_time&.utc
   if date < Time.current
     self.update(booking_status: 'no_show')
     booking_status
   else
     booking_status
   end
end
```

if you don't want/need callbacks then use **update_column** instead.

**EDITED:**

If what you want is to parse the format this is how you can do it:

```rb
require 'time'
p Time.parse('16:20:00').utc
```

You can test the above snippet [here](https://repl.it/languages/ruby?v2=1).

Comment: actually this is the rake task i am trying to run every 5 minute. and the to_time didn't help me to convert the time to UTC on my staging environment.

Comment: If that is the case the second approach should speed up the process @San

Comment: Then you asked more than one thing because you mentioned that kind of the problem is that the rake task run slow

Comment: Answer Edited so you can parse to UTC

Comment: can we just  do require 'time' any where or do we need any gem for this?

Comment: no, you dont need a gem for it, also remember if the answer works pls mark it as accepted @San

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the staging area server has UTC time. check it, or post some an error log to what you got as error.

Comment: Do you have any idea why the booking time is storing time in UTC in my db.

Comment: it must be configured as such. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32229086/765194) is a complete clarification about it.