# Ruby on Rails docker, database, app timezone alignment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, timezone, postgresql-9.5

Rails 6.1.4.1

I want to have all my components using the same timezone

The dockerfile of my web services shows this:

```
FROM ruby:2.7.4
...
ENV TZ=Europe/Berlin
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
...
```

My docker-compose shows this:

```
...
services:
  web:
    environment:
      - TZ=Europe/Berlin

  pg:
    image: postgres:9.5-alpine
    environment:
      - TZ=Europe/Berlin
      - PGTZ=Europe/Berlin
...
```

My config environment shows this:

```
...
config.time_zone = 'Berlin' # Your local time zone
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
...
```

Then I can check the timezone on each layer.

**Inside my rails container via docker compose exec**

```
root@a69e9bbcc14c:/appuser# cat /etc/timezone
Europe/Berlin
root@a69e9bbcc14c:/appuser# date +"%Z %z"
CEST +0200
```

looks fine :-)

**Inside my pg instance via docker compose exec**

```
psql (9.5.16)
Type "help" for help.

development=# show timezone;
   TimeZone    
---------------
 Europe/Berlin
(1 row)
```

looks fine :-)

**Inside my rails console via docker exec on my rails container** (the same rails container above)

```
Loading development environment (Rails 6.1.4.1)
irb(main):003:0> Rails.application.config.time_zone
=> "Berlin"

irb(main):005:0> Rails.application.config.active_record.default_timezone
=> :local
```

looks fine :-)

```
irb(main):004:0> puts Time.current.inspect
Tue, 26 Oct 2021 19:43:33.355250213 CEST +02:00
```

looks fine :-)

```
irb(main):001:0> Model.first.start_time
  Model Load (4.6ms)  SELECT "models".* FROM "models" ORDER BY "models"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> 2020-09-24 00:00:00 +0200
```

looks fine :-)

**However**

```
irb(main):002:0> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("show timezone;").first
   (0.5ms)  show timezone;
=> {"TimeZone"=>"UTC"}
```

How does it look like? Is this correct? Am I doing the wrong configuration or the wrong test?
Am I missing something?

I really expect to have {"TimeZone"=>"Europe/Berlin"} for the last check or something equivalent.

Comment: Hey, this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118779/how-to-change-default-timezone-for-active-record-in-rails